# Starting activity from fragment force closes app

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, actionbarsherlock

I am using ActionBarSherlock to display a couple of fragments. One of the fragments has a button which calls another activity. Clicking the button shows the new activity biefly before the app force closes. I have tried overriding the onSaveInstanceState() method.

login.java

```
public class login extends SherlockFragment implements OnClickListener {
Button login;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, container, false);


    login = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    login.setOnClickListener(this);

    return view;
    }

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("DO NOT CRASH", "OK");
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId()){

    case R.id.btnLogin : Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), success.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                            break;

    }
}
```

}

and here is the simple activity it calls.

success.java

```
public class success extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.success);
}
```

}

logcat error messages:

```
06-17 10:33:24.276: E/AndroidRuntime(13546): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-17 10:33:24.276: E/AndroidRuntime(13546): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-17 10:33:24.276: E/AndroidRuntime(13546): at  android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentBasicState(FragmentManager.java:1576)
06-17 10:33:24.276: E/AndroidRuntime(13546):    at  android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveAllState(FragmentManager.java:1617)
06-17 10:33:24.276: E/AndroidRuntime(13546):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(FragmentActivity.java:481)
06-17 10:33:24.276: E/AndroidRuntime(13546):    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:127)
06-17 10:33:24.276: E/AndroidRuntime(13546):    at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1147)
06-17 10:33:24.276: E/AndroidRuntime(13546):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1216)
06-17 10:33:24.276: E/AndroidRuntime(13546):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3129)
06-17 10:33:24.276: E/AndroidRuntime(13546):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3188)
06-17 10:33:24.276: E/AndroidRuntime(13546):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-17 10:33:24.276: E/AndroidRuntime(13546):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1261)
06-17 10:33:24.276: E/AndroidRuntime(13546):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-17 10:33:24.276: E/AndroidRuntime(13546):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-17 10:33:24.276: E/AndroidRuntime(13546):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-17 10:33:24.276: E/AndroidRuntime(13546):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-17 10:33:24.276: E/AndroidRuntime(13546):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-17 10:33:24.276: E/AndroidRuntime(13546):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-17 10:33:24.276: E/AndroidRuntime(13546):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-17 10:33:24.276: E/AndroidRuntime(13546):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: which is line 127 in SherlockFragmentActivity.

Comment: That seems to be weird ... can you try to start the Activity from parent? Something like: `getActivity().startActivity(i)`

Comment: remove onSaveInstanceState from fragment.. put it in perent activity..

Comment: Okay , so I added the onSaveInstanceState() method to all the fragments in the action bar tabs instead of just the one calling the activity. And now its not force closing. I can't quite understand what went wrong or what is right now.

Answer (score 0):

you just replace success extends activity to FragmentActivity.